# Print all nodes at distance k from a given node

Tags: algorithm, tree

[image]
The tree does not have any parent pointer.
If this is the graph and target is 10 and k is 2, then the output should be 150, 160,8,14. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-nodes-distance-k-given-node-binary-tree/ has a soluton which works though I am not able to understand it.

So I constructed a undirected graph from the tree as per the 1st answer. 
I think the complexity of my `printN` is not O(n). Can anyone please check that.
Thanks!

```
public class Nth {
    private int targetV;

    private class Node {
        private int data;
        private Node left, right;

        public Node() {
        }

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    private class GraphNode {
        private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> edgeMap;

        GraphNode() {
            edgeMap = new HashMap<>();
        }

        private void addEdge(int v, int w) {
            if (edgeMap.containsKey(v)) {
                if (!edgeMap.get(v).contains(w))
                    edgeMap.get(v).add(w);
            } else {
                edgeMap.put(v, new ArrayList<>());
                edgeMap.get(v).add(w);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Nth().job1();
    }

    private void job1() {
        Node root = new Node(20);
        root.left = new Node(8);
        root.left.left = new Node(4);
        root.left.right = new Node(12);
        root.left.right.left = new Node(10);
        root.left.right.left.left = new Node(50);
        root.left.right.left.left.left = new Node(150);
        root.left.right.left.left.left.left = new Node(1250);
        root.left.right.left.left.left.right = new Node(12512);
        root.left.right.left.left.right = new Node(160);
        root.left.right.left.right = new Node(60);
        root.left.right.right = new Node(14);
        root.right = new Node(22);
        GraphNode graphNode = new GraphNode();
        generateGraph(null, null, root, graphNode, 10);
        check(graphNode);
        // printN(graphNode, 2);
    }

private void printN(GraphNode graphNode, int k) {
    Set<Integer> items = new HashSet<>();
    Queue<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    queue.add(targetV);
    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put(targetV, true);
    for (int e = 0; e < k; e++) {
        items.clear();
        Queue<Integer> back = new ArrayDeque<>();
        back.addAll(queue);
        int xq = back.size();
        queue.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < xq; i++) {
            int polled = back.poll();
            ArrayList<Integer> list = graphNode.edgeMap.get(polled);
            list.forEach((x) -> {
                if (!hashMap.containsKey(x)) {
                    queue.add(x);
                    hashMap.put(x, true);
                }
            });
        }
        items.addAll(queue);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items.toArray()));
}

    private void check(GraphNode graphNode) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> pop : graphNode.edgeMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(pop.getKey() + "\t\t\t" + Arrays.toString(pop.getValue().toArray()));
        }
    }

    private void generateGraph(Node parent, Node root, Node child, GraphNode graphNode, int target) {
        if (child == null && root != null && parent != null)
            graphNode.addEdge(root.data, parent.data);
        if (child == null) return;
        if (root != null) graphNode.addEdge(root.data, child.data);
        if (parent != null && root != null) graphNode.addEdge(root.data, parent.data);
        if (child.data == target) targetV = child.data;
        generateGraph(root, child, child.left, graphNode, target);
        generateGraph(root, child, child.right, graphNode, target);
    }

}
```

My check fun prints:

```
        160         [50]
        1250        [150]
        1251        [150]
        4           [8]
        8           [4, 20, 12]
        10          [50, 12, 60]
        12          [10, 8, 14]
        14          [12]
        50          [150, 10, 160]
        20          [8, 22]
        150         [1250, 50, 1251]
        22          [20]
        60          [10]
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't look at it as a tree. Look at it as usual connected bi-directional graph and start BFS from selected vertex. Track all unique vertexes on k-th step/depth of your BFS search.

Comment: You can still construct that graph with O(n) even without parent pointer.

Comment: I can't understand, can you suggest me some code or example.

Comment: anything ?, how would I go up from target?

Comment: When you go down track parent this way you have edge for your graph.

Comment: Can you please a bit detailed steps? The way I see it is   1) start from root    2)Add the left and right nodes as vertex 3)do step 2 for the whole tree 4)start bfs and then get the nodes

Comment: @NikhilVerma I think you make this complicated without any reason. Just run BFS from source and your state is the distance from the source ( when you transition to node you increase the distance + 1 keeping track of visited nodes )

Comment: @serhiyb I coded the way you told me, please see if it is right ?, I think the complexity of my printN function is not O(n).Thanks!

Comment: Hey Nikhil. You should have a queue of <current position, path length>. Initially this queue will have your starting vertex with path length = 0. Until queue is empty - you extract top one element <u,L> and if vertex u was never visited (you can have bool array to track which vertexes were visited) you mark this vertex as visited and you check length (if L == k) you save this vertex since you get here within k steps and move to next pair in your queue. if (L < k) you iterate over current vertex edges <u,v> and enque new pair (v, k+1). Hope that helps.

Comment: And since you can visit each vertex only once - complexity will be O(|vertexes| + |edges|). Since we have binary tree |edges| = |vertexes| - 1 which gives us O(|vertexes|) = O(n) total complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm given in the link, which you are trying to understand currently, is separated into two parts:

1. Find all children of the target node that is `k` away from the target node
2. Find other nodes (i.e. not children nodes) that are `k` away from the target node

I am sure you understood how to solve 1, which is easily done with a BFS from the target node.

Your understanding of how to solve 2, however, is incorrect.

Starting from the root of the tree, as we traverse the tree to find the target node, keep track of all ancestors (including the root) of the target node.

Then:

- Parent node of target node is 1 away from the target. Thus perform BFS from the parent node to find all nodes that are `k-1` from the parent node.
- Grandparent node of target node is 2 away from the target. Thus perform BFS from the grandparent node to find all nodes that are `k-2` from the grandparent node.
- Great-grandparent node of target node is 3 away from the target. Thus perform BFS from the great-grandparent node to find all nodes that are `k-3` from the great-grandparent node.
- etc. all the way up to the root of the tree, if need be i.e. if `k` is large enough for this to be required.

When performing BFS from the ancestors, you just need to be careful not to traverse back down to the target node.

---

Finally I would like to add that a much simpler algorithm would be:

1. Fully traverse the tree once to create parent pointers (why wouldn't you have parent pointers? To save 32/64 bits required for each pointer?)
2. Perform BFS from the target node traversing parent pointers as well as child pointers.

Comment: I got it to work, by constructing a undirected graph from the tree, can you check my code that is it fine, I think the complexity of my printN function is not O(n). Thanks!

Comment: You have completely changed your question, almost to the point that makes my answer seem completely irrelevant. My explanation on how to solve the problem without parent pointers, which directly answered your original question, now became unnecessary.